# split a 60GB flat file with records occasionally spanning multiple lines

Tags: files, split

Manual input of data makes a database polluted with records containing multiple newline characters. For good records delimited by double quotes in the beginning and at the end in a huge 60GB flat file with only a single column, they should always span only one line like this:

> "Complete sequences of numerous mitochondrial, many prokaryotic, and
>   several nuclear genomes are now available. "

For bad records, they span indefinite number of multiple lines like this:

> "Current smoking was strongly and inversely associated with high-risk
>
> patterns, after adjustment for concomitant risk factors. Relative to
>   never
>
> smokers, current smokers were significantly less likely to have a
>   high-risk
>
> pattern. "

These multi-line records prohibit downstream file splitting by the UNIX command `split`. `split` cannot intelligently recognize those multiple lines as a single record and this can lead to splitting a single record into separate files. The Perl below is too slow to merge those lines for the bad records first for this huge file before splitting, as $count cannot be printed after waiting for more than 2 hours.

```perl
$file=$ARGV[0];
open(INFO, $file) or die("Could not open $file.");
open(OUT, ">out") or die("Could not open $file.");

$mergedline = "";
$count=0;
foreach $line (<INFO>)  {
    print $count++;
    if ($line =~ /^".*"\n$/) {
                print OUT $line;
                $mergedline = "";
                next;
        } elsif ($line =~ /"\n$/) {
                print OUT $mergedline;
                $mergedline = "";
                next;
        } else {
                chomp $line;
                $mergedline .= $line;
        }
}
close(INFO);
```

Any handy UNIX command to solve this problem so that the output file is "clean" with only single-line records that can be processed by `split`?

`sed` appears to be an option, but neither of the following posts answer this question:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15758814/turning-multiple-lines-into-one-line-with-comma-separated-perl-sed-awk

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11290616/sed-conditional-merge-of-multiple-lines

http://www.unix.com/shell-programming-and-scripting/80633-sed-combining-multiple-lines-into-one.html

because their patterns of these posts are too regular and constant.

Comment: What is a "record"? What does the actual input file look like and what output do you expect? How can we identify a record? Is it any quoted string with no `"` characters inside it? Please [edit] your question and clarify. Also explain what Perl command you tried.

Comment: You have strings of text / sentences / paragraphs that are sometimes split in the middle with newlines? How come Perl is too slow to to merge them? It might be, if you try to deal with the full 60 GB _twice_, once to merge and once to split, but that should be doable in a pipeline.

Comment: Can you modify the file in place first with something like `sed` and then `split` it?

Comment: I feel like I've just read Chapter 2 of a three-chapter book. Please tell us the whole story. What is "this problem"? Presenting code you've tried is good — don't remove it from the question — but explain what you are doing *in English **also**.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `sed` to join the splitted lines only

```
sed ':a
/".*"$/b
N;s/\n/ /;ba' input >> output
```

takes 6 seconds for a 10 MB file on my system. This would be 10 hours for 60 GB.

`bbe` is a little faster

```
bbe -b '/"/:/"/' -o output -e 'y/\n/ /' input
```

but still takes 4 seconds.

I'm afraid those scripting languages are not the tool to perform good on extremly large files. How about writing a small program in `C`?

Answer (score 0):

example using `gawk`:

```
awk 'BEGIN {RS = "\"\n"} {++n; print $0"\""> n".txt"}' input
```

This says split the file `input` on any sequence of `"` followed by a newline (`\n`).  This will ignore newlines that don't immediately follow a quote mark, preserving multiline records.  In this example, output is written to a text file, but if you removed the `> n".txt"` portion, you could send records to a pipeline instead.

Comment: This command splits records into independent files but they remain multiple lined. Yet, this is already good enough for post-processing and therefore should also be accepted as a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Your `Perl` is slow because of the `for` loop being used to read in the file. You should really be using the `while` loop, since the `for` loop loads the whole file in memory at one go. That's why it's taking forever to print $count.

```
perl -ne '
   print,next if /^".*"$/m or /"$/m;
   chomp, $_ .= <>, redo unless eof;
' gene.data
```